# why the results from the joint_tests function (emmeans package) do not show one of the interactions of the model?

Tags: mixed-models, emmeans

I run a GLMM_adaptive model (I am doing a resource selection function) and I am using the joint_tests function (emmeans package) to compute joint tests of the terms in the model. The problem is that one of the interactions does not appear in the results.

The model is:

```
mod.hinc <- mixed_model(fixed = Used ~  scale(ndvi) * season * vegfactor + 
                      scale(ndvi^2) + scale(distance^2) + scale(distance) * season, 
                    random = ~ 1 | id, data = hin.c,
                    family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

After running the model I run the joint_tests function:

```
install.packages("emmeans")
library(emmeans)
joint_tests(mod.hinc)
```

And this is the result:

```
 joint_tests(mod.hinc)
 model term            df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 ndvi                    1 Inf  36.465  <.0001
 season                  3 Inf  22.265  <.0001
 vegfactor               4 Inf   4.548  0.0011
 distance                1 Inf  33.939  <.0001
 ndvi:season             3 Inf  13.826  <.0001
 ndvi:vegfactor          4 Inf   8.500  <.0001
 season:vegfactor       12 Inf   6.544  <.0001
 ndvi:season:vegfactor  12 Inf   5.165  <.0001
```

I cannot find the reason why the interaction scale(distance)*season does not appear in the results.

Any help on that issue is welcome. I can provide more details about the model if is required.

Thank you very much in advance.

Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that `distance:season` is not shown because it came up with zero d.f. for the associated interaction contrasts. You could verify this by running `joint_tests(mod.hinc, show0df = TRUE)`.

Why it has 0 d.f. is less clear. However, that is not the only problem here. You have to be extremely careful with numeric predictors when using `joint_tests()`; it does not do a model ANOVA; instead, as documented, it constructs a reference grid from the fitted model and performs joint tests of interaction contrasts related to the predictors. With numeric predictors, the results depend on the reference grid used.

In this particular instance, the model includes quadratic effects of `ndvi` and `distance`; however, the default reference grid is constructed using the range of the covariates -- only two distinct values. Thus, we can pick up the effects of the overall linear trends, but not the curvature effects implied by the quadratic terms. That's why only 1 d.f. of those factors' main effects are tested. There are really 2 d.f. in the effects of `ndvi` and `distance`. In order to capture all of those effects, we need to have at least three distinct values of these covariates in the reference grid. *One way* (not the only way) to accomplish that is to reduce the covariates to their means, plus or minus 1 SD -- which can be accomplished via this code:

```
meanpm1sd <- function(x)
    c(mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x))

joint_tests(mod.hinc, cov.reduce = meanpm1sd)
```

This will yield a different set of joint tests that likely will include 2-d.f. tests of `ndvi` and `distance`. But I don't know if you will still have some interactions missing due to zero-d.f. dimensionalities.

You can look directly at the estimates being tested in detail if you have any questions about what those effects are. For example, for `season:distance`,

```
### construct the needed reference grid once and for all
RG <- ref_grid(mod.h1nc, cov.reduce = meanpm1sd)   

EMM <- emmeans(RG, ~ season * distance)
CON <- contrast(EMM, interaction = "consec")

EMM   ### see estimates
CON   ### see interaction contrasts
test(CON, joint = TRUE)
```

I hope this helps shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: Thak you very much for your help. I used the suggested code to take into account the quadratic effect of these variables and I could extract the stimates of the distance:season interaction. What I am not totally sure is about wheter I should include the interaction between the quadratic effects of the covariates (ndvi and distance) and the factors (season and vegfactor). The models show pronblems of convergence when I include them but I am not sure if it is correct to include both variables (with and without the quadratic effect) while only including the interaction for the non-quadratic parts

Comment: Personally, I'd include the quadratic effects in the interaction. And I'd also *not* scale the linear and quadratic effects separately; that just looks awkward to me. So my fixed-effects model would be something like `used ~ poly(scale(ndvi), scale(distance), degree = 2) * vegfactor * distance` (note this includes the interaction of `ndvi` and `distance` as well).  If my answer is useful to you, I would appreciate your accepting and/or up-voting it.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer! I will try this option and I hope this will not create any problem of convergence. I have accepted your answer. Sorry but I did not know that I can accept it and I just tried to vote it but I have not the required level of reputation to do it. Now your answer is accepted. Thank you again as your answer and comments have been really useful.