# Obtain F-ratio and p-value for the continuous predictor

Tags: r, emmeans, ancova

I fitted a linear model with block as a fixed factor, plus 2 categorical and 1 continuous predictors. I'd like a Type III ANCOVA table with all the effects averaged over blocks.

```
dput(rye)
structure(list(strain = c("S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", 
"S23", "S23", "S23", "NZ", "NZ", "NZ", "NZ", "NZ", "NZ", "NZ", 
"NZ", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Kent", "Kent", 
"Kent", "Kent", "Kent", "Kent", "Kent", "Kent"), manure = c("H", 
"H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", "H", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "H", "H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "A", "A", "A", "A"), block = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4), yield = c(299, 318, 284, 279, 247, 202, 171, 183, 315, 
247, 289, 307, 257, 175, 188, 174, 403, 439, 355, 324, 222, 170, 
192, 176, 382, 353, 383, 310, 233, 246, 200, 143), moisture = c(65.4073415007189, 
37.0145280041042, 73.2225001374652, 39.9941837349335, 74.803410076096, 
42.8914147357587, 50.792780124357, 55.0153723560264, 47.217016572995, 
62.3885361519854, 53.7388755272386, 24.6856936491391, 34.8364200180523, 
37.9399805638271, 37.7866881025361, 58.1848457395229, 39.2165119122411, 
45.0354704343593, 55.1876133744328, 42.272547076364, 61.2191532302273, 
62.5368880571047, 36.1336423251218, 40.8096323034628, 23.8425007638943, 
55.7644071035274, 66.9264524519492, 49.8050708164737, 60.5314496784137, 
82.4221025517919, 52.8870034752968, 54.0634811725579)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(strain = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), manure = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), block = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), yield = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x7ff0af81bf90>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))  

rye_lm <- lm(yield ~ block + strain*manure*moisture, data = rye)
```

The only way I can get the F-value and P-value for the continuous predictor, and the interaction terms with the categorical variables are `joint_tests(rye_lm)` , which gives

```
 model term             df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 block                    1  15  20.144  0.0004
 strain                   3  15   3.742  0.0345
 manure                   1  15 144.076  <.0001
 moisture                 1  15   0.175  0.6820
 strain:manure            3  15   6.001  0.0068
 strain:moisture          3  15   1.554  0.2419
 manure:moisture          1  15   1.128  0.3050
 strain:manure:moisture   3  15   0.567  0.6452
```

which is similar to the suggestions here [why the results from the joint_tests function (emmeans package) do not show one of the interactions of the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762933/why-the-results-from-the-joint-tests-function-emmeans-package-do-not-show-one)

Using these codes gives an ANOVA table for the categorical predictors only

```
rye_emm <- emmeans(rye_lm, c("strain", "manure", "moisture"))
joint_tests(rye_emm)
 model term    df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 strain          3  15   3.966  0.0289
 manure          1  15 162.312  <.0001
 strain:manure   3  15   6.178  0.0060
```

How do I change my code so that I get the F-ratio and p-value for the 2 categorical, the continuous predictors, and their interactions, without the block? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try doing it based on emmeans with every predictor except block, using `at` to specify 2 different levels of the continuous ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. This works `emmeans(rye_lm , ~ strain * manure | moisture, at = list(moisture = c(40, 55)))`. Just a clarification question: Why do we specify 2 levels of the continuous variable? I notice that specifying 3 levels returns an additional column to the ANOVA table `d: df1 reduced due to linear dependence`.

Comment: You need to have 2 values and not 1 because it is based on creating contrasts between levels so the effect is quantifiable. If you specify 3 levels, it works, but will over-determine it and hence lead to that message. Also, if you use > 2 unequally spaced levels, it will bias it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rye_emm2 <-  emmeans(rye_lm , ~ strain * manure | moisture, at = list(moisture = c(40, 55)))

joint_tests(rye_emm2)
 model term             df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 strain                   3  15   4.337  0.0217
 manure                   1  15 169.648  <.0001
 moisture                 1  15   0.175  0.6820
 strain:manure            3  15   5.847  0.0075
 strain:moisture          3  15   1.554  0.2419
 manure:moisture          1  15   1.128  0.3050
 strain:manure:moisture   3  15   0.567  0.6452
```